# Python script to access one of the resources responses of a given webpage

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the Json response of one of the resources (line highlighted) automatically called by the URL I'm calling (first line).

1. I've tried to reconstruct the response's URL (highlighted) but I failed (I can't find from where some part of it are coming)
2. Even if I could, it seems like there are numerous other parameters to specify (cookies, etc.) and a bunch of previous resources called (that might include pieces of the puzzle)

[image]

Is there something like requests that can "cascade" the resources and let me choose the one I want the response to be saved ?

PS: there is far more in the response Json I want to save than in the content of the page for which I query the URL shown in a web browser)

Comment: Right clicking on the resource and selecting "Copy as Fetch" will give you the information you need. You'll have to translate from JavaScript to Python, though.

Comment: hi @edemaine thanks for your answer but i'm not sure that i understand what you mean : copy as fetch is just copying the path and the headers... what i want is a python script to get this, and the response content, when i specify the very first URL ! thanks